# C call function type error

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm trying to compile this code which call func from "libcfmapi.so" to decrypt "cfg" file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int restorebackup(const char *tmp_cfg_name,const char *xml_cfg_name);
int ATP_CFM_ExtCustomImportEncryptedUserCfgFile(const char *tmp_cfg_name);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int ret;
if(argc < 3)
{
printf("specify temp config file name.\n");
exit(1);
}
ret=restorebackup(argv[1],argv[2]);
return ret;
}
int restorebackup(const char *tmp_cfg_name,const char *xml_cfg_name)
{
int ret=0;
//ret = ATP_CFM_ExtDigVerifyFile(tmp_cfg_name,tmp_cfg_name);
if(ret != 0)
{
printf("Verify File failed.\n");
return ret;
}
ret = ATP_CFM_ExtCustomImportEncryptedUserCfgFile(tmp_cfg_name);
return ret;
}
```

but got error regarding func type declare

```
root@kali:~/debian-qemu# gcc  h.c   -o demo
    /tmp/ccVbt5NT.o: In function `restorebackup':
    h.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `ATP_CFM_ExtCustomImportEncryptedUserCfgFile'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

any help appreciated

Comment: please post your code as text and also the error message. Don't try to "simplify" it for us.

Comment: sorry its appear like mess even with code func I will try

Comment: don't be sorry. just copy/paste the text, it's even simpler that what you're doing. You'll get a lot of answers instead of downvotes. and also include your build script the problem is in the link phase.

Comment: you need to add `-latputil` at the end of your compile command.

Comment: got : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latputil

Comment: ooops try: `-lcfmapi` instead.

Comment: same /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcfmapi

Comment: for readability of the posted code,  consistently indent the code.  one method is to highlite the code then click the `{}` button.  Another (and IMO: better method) is to write the code properly indented.  Indent after every opening brace '{".  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces (never use tabs for indenting) as 4 spaces is wide enough to be visible even when using a variable width font.

Comment: OT: "*`root@kali`*": You are doing dangerous! If ever possible, do not develop, test even use the *root* account!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

when using a library, then must:

1. include that library in the link statement via

   `-l cfmapi`
2. include the header file for that library in the source code:

   `#include <cfmapi.h>`

Comment: haven't  h.file cfmapi.h

Comment: with out the appropriate header file for the library you are trying to use, there is no way to be able to access any functions within that library, UNLESS you have the source code for the library and can extract the needed function signatures, etc from that source code.

Comment: @user3629249 This is plain wrong... You CAN do without headers to use a library. You CAN'T use it without the actual library

Comment: @IshayPeled,    Sure, you 'can' use a library without having the associated header file.  However, unless the source code contains prototypes for the functions, etc in the library, the compiler will make several assumptions (most of which are usually not correct)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're not linking against the required library, `libcfmapi.so`.

This is not a library you would expect to find in your Debian system as it is unique to the BT device you're trying to hack.

In short - get the lib from your device, cross compile to the device architecture against the lib you extracted from the device and you should be fine.

Comment: libcfmapi.so copied to deb mips environment  & try to compile the code same error                                              root@debian-mips:~# gcc  h.c   -o demo -lcfmapi
/tmp/ccr3fB2v.o: In function `restorebackup':
h.c:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `ATP_CFM_ExtCustomImportEncryptedUserCfgFile'

Comment: Good. Two things: 1. do `readelf -s <target libcfmapi.so> | grep ATP_CFM_ExtCustomImportEncryptedUserCfgFile` to verify that function indeed exist. 2. If it does exist, try stating explicitely where the library is with the -L flag (`gcc h.c -o demo -lcfmapi -L<libcfmapi.so location>`)

Comment: That means the function is not declared in the .so file (as I suspected). Try pulling this library from the device you're hacking and run nm on it

Comment: nm: libcfmapi.so: no symbols

Comment: @MHAyhm Sorry, try `readelf -s <pulled library>` instead of nm

Comment: Don't be here is result       Dynamic symbol information is not available for displaying symbols.

Comment: Well, if `readelf -s <pulled library> | grep ATP_CFM_ExtCustomImportEncryptedUserCfgFile` comes out empty, that means the library does not contain the symbol which is the reason you're getting an `undefined reference` error. Nothing much to be done about it, you're missing the library

Comment: well I check for other func in another lib (libatshared.so) the same result for readelf.... hmmm dont know why cant call libs

Comment: Well the problem isn't linking - its that the function you call doesn't exist in those libraries

Comment: IDA libcfmapi.so say func exist

Comment: maybe its big , little endian mess?

Comment: `readelf` should handle big/little just fine, where did you see this function exists?

Comment: fun. appear when loading libcfmapi.so in IDA debugger

Answer (score 0):

More information based on Ishay Peled answer:

```
readelf -s <pulled library> | grep ATP_CFM_ExtCustomImportEncryptedUserCfgFile
```

I suspect the problem isn't that function you call doesn't exist but rather there are no functions being displayed it is most likely empty just like nm result:

> nm: libcfmapi.so: no symbols

do the command without piping to grep, my bet is your output is:

```
readelf -s libcfmapi.so
```

> Dynamic symbol information is not available for displaying symbols.

If someone knows the way of getting the headers from the file, i believe then you can find your function you require then link and run (i too am trying to use libcfmapi.so, but lack the programming/reversing knowledge required).